# Save data typed into PDF Form

Tags: pdf

Hey I have PDF Form which would not let me save the data typed into it.  Here is the form:

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm0008egen.pdf

I want it to save the data typed into it so that I can email it to my relative.  Any ideas?  I'm using Acrobat Reader.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/support/forums/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to edit and save it using [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/). It is not "password protected" unlike what vartec says.

Answer (score 0):

It's a password protected PDF. **Saving is not allowed**. It is possible to crack this password (it's 128-bit RC4) and there are even on-line applications to do it. But in many countries  it'd be a serious crime (while in others it's perfectly legal).

Comment: According to @Steven this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of an idea. well I can fill the form and then take its screen shot, but I want to take the screen shot of the whole page, zoomed, How to do this?

And the scroll part too.